# protocol compilation using a remote file for Python (and others)

Tags: bash, protocol-buffers, protoc

I am looking for a way to convince bash that "I've passed you a file, in the specified directory" without actually downloading and creating that directory on disk, OR pass a remote file directly to my protocol buffer compiler without writing it to disk.

I would like my protocol buffers compiler to look at a remote file, compile my classes, then finish without the `.proto` ever being downloaded.

I have this script which is getting us by for now

```
git archive --remote=git@bitbucket.org:redzoneco/asset-pipeline-protocol-buffers.git master preflight_check_service/preflight.proto | tar -x 
preflight_check_service/preflight.proto
protoc --python_out=chalicelib/protos preflight_check_service/preflight.proto
rm -r preflight_check_service
```

but as you can see we make the directory locally, run `protoc`, then remove the file. Seems like a waste.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to avoid using a temp file/directory as protoc doesn't accept it's input via stdin.  There's an open ticket [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/4163), but it has received very little attention.

You could always just drop the .proto file into your destination and not worry about it.  So, in your example, put it in `chalicelib/protos`.  That'd help document what was created and why.  (...for others if this is checked into source control, or just for your self if not.)